# Method porting desktop to web

Tags: web, cross-platform, reverse-engineering, desktop, porting

I'm working on a thesis about porting desktop applications to the web. Does anyone know the method or stages in doing the porting? Previously I had searched for some papers on google but it was very difficult. So I tried to ask here maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

in my humble opinion, there are stages / method with their own cases. Maybe if we analyze what they do and find the similiar what the others do, it seem good enough to implement in case desktop to web.